# Promote the topic challenges across SE

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, topic-challenge

I wish I'd known about the topic challenge Icelandic Sagas when it happened. Likewise, I'm sure there are people that are interested in some of the current challenges. Is there any way these challenges could be advertised across the SE network?

Comment: [We are represented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295163/348200) on main meta's post about topic challenges, fr example ;)

Comment: For the first topic challenge (about a Russian sci-fi novel), we advertised it in the chatrooms of the various Russian-language SE sites and of Sci-Fi & Fantasy SE. There wasn't such a clear place to advertise the Icelandic Sagas one, since SE doesn't have any Scandinavian-language sites.

Comment: But of course you can still ask questions about Icelandic sagas any time! :-) I think we have at least one expert on-site. TBH, that challenge was a bit of a flop; it'd be nice to see more questions even if they're 'too late'.

Comment: @Randal'Thor you could have advertised it on mythology. Though I wouldn't have seen it then, either, unfortunately. I might be asking some questions about Icelandic sagas, I've gotten quite excited about Norse mythology recently =)

Answer (score 5):

Yeah! You could post messages in relevant chat rooms, for example. Or if you know someone who might be interested, give them a ping. I would suggest community promotion ads, but we've already posted them.

Now that I think about it, chat events are annoying features that have a decent amount of visibility. Maybe we could try using those.

That said, our recruitment/promotion efforts are mostly focused on Twitter and Tumblr at the moment, and in my opinion rightfully so. Twitter and Tumblr have large communities of book/lit lovers, and these communities have hashtags/etc that allow us to reach a lot of people at once. The situation at SE is the opposite: smaller number of people who would be interested in our content, they're scattered across different sites, and the HNQ already does a better job getting our name out there than we ever could. (Of course, the HNQ isn't without its consequences, but that's a story for another day).

Comment: Are you guys active on reddit, by any chance?

Comment: @Heather no, but submitting links to questions would definitely help get the word out. So if that's something you want to do, please do it.

Comment: [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/literature/comments/6sxg1g/literature_stack_exchange_a_great_site_for/)

Comment: @Heather you'll probably have better luck if you submit links to questions you find interesting.

Comment: "*the HNQ already does a better job getting our name out there than we ever could*" - I don't think Lit has had a single HNQ for weeks. (I've been having some thoughts about this recently, actually - will ping you in chat when I've formulated them properly.)

Comment: @Rand we really shouldn't be focused on promoting the site on Stack, because compared to other websites, less people are interested in our topic on Stack, and those people are scattered across different places. I get the sense people try to use the HOW because it's easier than Twitter or Tumblr, not because it actually works.

Comment: @Rand and i think some of my book collecting questions hit the HNQ a few weeks ago. Anyway. If we get a HNQ, then we deal with the consequences and try to capture the benifits. *Dont* try to game the system and seak out HNQs, don't lower our quality standards, etc etc.